# web2py a form for processing a value

Tags: web2py

This is probably very simple, sorry in advance!
I have a form defined in a model file:

```
db.define_table('table1',
    Field('X', 'integer'))
```

I have a controller that is also defined as:

```
def index():
    form = SQLFORM(db.X)
    return dict(form=form)
```

In my index view file I have:

```
<h2>Input form</h2>
{{=form}}
```

I want to use value X in a scheduler defined as a model like:

```
A = X+2
```

The form shows up as expected. I enter a value in it and submit it. The scheduler is running as expected. However it looks like the value X never gets set to what I enter.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the submitted value to be inserted in the database, you need to process the form:

```
def index():
    form = SQLFORM(db.X).process()
    return dict(form=form)
```

Once the value has been inserted in the database, it should be available for your scheduler task to access.

Comment: Thank you, yes right now the database gets the new values. One last question, it seems that the new entered value of X is not being used. I reference it as   
 'db.Table1.X', this must be wrong because it does not use the updated value.

Comment: `db.Table1.X` is just a Field object -- it doesn't refer to any record. For a record, you need to run a query -- something like `db().select(db.Table1.X, orderby=~db.Table1.id, limitby=(0, 1))`.